# How do I wire up ModelAndViewDefiningException to send errors to my view

Tags: spring, modelandview

In the easiest, most straightforward way, how do I wire up a/the ModelAndViewDefiningException doodad to send errors to my specified view?

This guy should be called from: **org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndViewDefiningException**

Much thanks to anyone in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> How do I wire up ModelAndViewDefiningException to send errors to my view?

**It's an exception. You throw it!**

The `ModelAndViewDefiningException` is an exception wrapper for a `ModelAndView`. The Spring framework recognizes it, catches it, extracts the model and view name from it and forwards to the resolved view exposing the model to the view.

```
...
if (someBadThingy) {
  ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("errorView"); // "errorView" name resolved to a view by the ViewResolver of your app
  throw new ModelAndViewDefiningException(modelAndView);
}
...
```

You can throw it at any time during handler processing. Normally, inside a [Controller](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/Controller.html)'s code  you don't usually throw the exception because Controller request handler methods return a `ModelAndView`. So instead of throwing an exception with the `ModelAndView` inside, you can just return the `ModelAndView`.

But there are situations when you can't return a `ModelAndView`. [Interceptors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) are a good example of this because their methods are of `void` or `boolean` return. If some condition isn't met inside the interceptor the `ModelAndViewDefiningException` allows you to break the flow and go to the error view.